# setDataSource from passed string not detected

Tags: string, media-player, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

I created a listview which contain a url such as abc:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1

When I click the listview,the url would be passed onto the next class and use it for setDataSource.But the problem I am having is that setDataSource does not detect the url.I have tried to hardcode the url and use Toast to display the url when it is trying to connect and it works.But when passing the string,nothing happens.Here are my code

**1st class trying to pass the string**

```
OnItemClickListener getURLOnItemClickListener
        = new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String clickedFile = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        getURL(clickedFile);
    }

};

void getURL(final String file){
    if (clickAble == true){
        FileInputStream fis;
        String content = "";
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(file);
            byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
            while (fis.read(input) != -1) {}
            content += new String(input);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),content,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(addressActivity.this, liveActivity.class);
        String strName = content.toString();
        i.putExtra("urlAddress", strName);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**2nd class where the passed string is set**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);
    final String newString;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            newString = null;
        } else {
            newString = extras.getString("urlAddress");
        }
    } else {
        newString = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("urlAddress");
    }
    urlLink = "rtsp://" + newString + "&stream=1.sdp?";
    videoPlay();
}
void videoPlay(){
    mPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
    mCallback1 = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            try {
                mPlayer1.setDataSource(urlLink);
                mPlayer1.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mPlayer1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mPlayer1.start();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connecting...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                mPlayer1.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            mPlayer1.release();
        }
    };
    final SurfaceView surfaceView1 =
            (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    // Configure the Surface View.
    surfaceView1.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    // Configure the Surface Holder and register the callback.
    SurfaceHolder holder1 = surfaceView1.getHolder();
    holder1.addCallback(mCallback1);
    holder1.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find the answer and it was ridiculously plain and simple.On the second class around these lines of codes on the top

```
final String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras == null) {
        newString = null;
    } else {
        newString = extras.getString("urlAddress");
    }
} else {
    newString = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("urlAddress");
}
urlLink = "rtsp://" + newString + "&stream=1.sdp?";
videoPlay();
}
```

All I did was change

```
urlLink = "rtsp://" + newString + "&stream=1.sdp?";
```

into

```
urlLink = "rtsp://" + newString.toString().trim() + "&stream=1.sdp?";
```

Just adding toString() did not work,so I tried adding trim() and it works.If someone can explain it to me why this work it would be much appreciated